# How I can read errors that occurred in the BBDD as processes incomplete in MS-SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008

How I can to recognize the processes that failed on the SQL Server/bd, processes that any user run/exec.

For example the last rollback occurred in the bd after some process failed.

Would reading error  log help ? i.e  I use `exec sys.xp_readerrorlog` but it returns only login errors.